# Is there a built in routine to convert lightuserdata to int?

Tags: lua

Lightuserdata is different from userdata so what can I do with it? I mean the operations of lightuserdata in lua. Looks like I cannot convert it to any other data type.

One of my case:

My C library returns a C pointer named 'c_pointer', AKA lightuserdata to Lua, and then I want:

my_pointer = c_pointer +4

and then pass 'my_pointer' back to C library. Since I cannot do anything with 'c_pointer', so the expression 'c_pointer + 4' is invalid.

I am wondering are there some practical solutions to this?

Comment: No there isn't.  What were you expecting?

Comment: @finnw yes I am returning a C pointer to lua and I want to do something based on it, like: my_pointer = c_pointer + 4, and then pass my_pointer back to c library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightuserdata are created by C libraries. They are simply C pointers.

For example, you can use them to refer to data you allocate with `malloc`, or statically allocate in your module. Your C library can transfer these pointers to the Lua side as a lightuserdata using `lua_pushlightuserdata`, and later Lua can give it back to your library (or other C code) on the stack. Lua code can use the lightuserdata as any other value, storing it in a table, for example, even as a table key.

ADDENDUM

To answer your revised question, if you want to add an offset to the pointer, do it on the C side. Pass the lightuserdata and the integer offset to C, and let C do the offset using `ptr[n]`

```
void * ptr = lua_touserdata(L, idx1);
lua_Integer n = lua_tointeger(L. idx2);
// do something with
((char *)ptr)[n];
```

Comment: What you mean 'Lua code can use the lightuserdata as any other value'? don't it need to be converted first? I've tried 'nonumber' with a lightuserdata, but failed

Comment: What I mean is that it may be passed as an argument to functions, returned as a result from a function, stored in a table as a key or a value, and assigned to variables (local or global). It cannot be converted to any other type, though it can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Lua has no pointer arithmetic, so as [Doug Currie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16409664) stated you would need to do the pointer arithmetic on the C side.

[LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) on the other hand can do pointer arithmetic (via the [FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html) library), so consider using that instead.